# How do we estimate weights of nodes in temporal networks?

Tags: graph-theory, spatio-temporal

I would like to know some approaches or techniques that are used to tackle this problem.

I would like to estimate the weight of every node over time. I have temporal-network with 50 nodes. At every time t (every 10 minutes) in a day di, I have snapshot of number of elements that moved from nodei to nodej.

I denote weight of edge e(i,j) as weij, and the weight of node i as `wi = Sum(Weij -Wki)` it's equal to all the weights coming to node j minus the nodes going out from node i.

As  a results I would have matrice X =

#### \time of day| 1 | 2 | ... | 144 |

#### node_1      | x1t1 | .. ..  | xit144

..

#### node_i      | xit1 | .. ..  | xit144

#### node_49      | x49t1 | .. ..  | x49t144

#### node_50      | x50t1 | .. ..  | x49t144

What's the name of these techniques that take into account the weigh of node instead of focusing on weight of edges ?

Are you aware of any application/paper where they use this weight of node to estimate future weight of node ?